# Change date in excel

Tags: excel, date, format

I am trying to change the date format of my cells in excel to another date format. Currently it is in this format: apr, 10, 2017 01:58:24 PM. I would like to have it in a normal format like dd-mm-yyyy without the time, but I can not get it to work with the formatting in excel.

Thanks in advance,
Kester

Comment: If excel recognizes the values as dates, simply select the cells to format, click the format drop-down and select `short date`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I tried that but I think excel can not recognize the current format

Comment: How do dates with day-number less that 10 look?  i.e. `apr, 01, 2017 01:58:24 PM` or `apr, 1, 2017 01:58:24 PM`

Comment: Days under the ten are with a zero in front, so apr 01, 2017 01:58:24 PM

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
=(MID(A2,FIND(",",A2)+2,FIND(",",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","@",1))-FIND(",",A2)-2)&"-"&LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1)&"-"&MID(A2,FIND(",",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","@",1))+2,LEN(A2)))*1
```

Which is basically a bit of string manipulation (and some substitution of `,` to `@` to help) to put it in the generic format 'd-m-y h:m:s t', which excel understands, then multiply the string by 1 to force into a number (in this case 42835.58222); which you only have to format as date (important!):

[image]

---

**Edit:** Per comments, the first comma doesn't actually exist, so the revised formula:

```
=(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,FIND(",",A2)-FIND(" ",A2)-1)&"-"&LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1)&"-"&MID(A2,FIND(",",A2)+2,LEN(A2)))*1
```

Comment: Hi Jerry, thank you for your comment. Im not sure why but I get an error when I try to use the code. Also I made an error on my part, the month and day are not separeted by a comman so: apr 06, 2017 03:42:14 PM. Im not sure if this changes much but when I tried the code with a comma added it did not works aswell.

Comment: @Kessie yep, it changes things. Give me a few secs

Comment: @Kessie Ok, added the adjusted one in the answer

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I also found out why it gave an error at first, my excel uses ; instead of commas

Comment: Sorry to ask you so much but I have one last problem. Your code works perfectly except or the month march which gives a #VALUE!. mrt 23, 2017 03:12:26 PM this is the way it is in the cells. mrt is the abreviation for march in Dutch, however some other months are also in Dutch and they still work with your code. Do you perhaps have an idea what causes this?

Comment: @Kessie hmm, I'm guessing it's still the march, but I cannot test it to ensure that's really it :( I tried testing it on google spreadsheet but it works well there with mrt when I change the language to dutch. What you can try is to test if using `mar` or something else works instead. If so, then let me know, I can edit the formula to handle this case separately

Comment: Im not sure why but it works when I type out maart entirely (march in Dutch). The weird things is that it doesnt work with mar or march. No idea why this is the case, but for now I just used the replace function to swap all the mrt with maart. Thank again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATE(MID(A1,10,4),MATCH(LEFT(A1,3),{"jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sep","oct","nov","dec"},0),MID(A1,6,2))
```

and apply desired formatting:

[image]

*(this results in a genuine Excel date that can be used in sorts, calculations, etc.)*
*(this assumes that the day field is always two digits)*
*(if your month list is in a language other than English, edit the month list)*